# How does the GC collect a Class reference by two threads

Tags: python-3.x, garbage-collection, python-multithreading

I have in my code a few worker threads that performas some work. The data from the work is collected into a small class which holds this information. This class is in put into a Queue for processing in the main thread.

When is this class collected by the GC?

Short Sodu excample:

```
def run(in_q, out_q):
  lp = lpClass()

  # Do work and add info in class
  workToDo = in_q.get_nowait()

  while working:
    lp.add(work data)

  out_q.put_nowait(lp)


# main

t = thread(run, in_q, out_q)
t.start()
in_q.put_nowait(some work)
t.join()

while out_q.not_empty:
  lp = out_q.get()

  print(lp.getData())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python's garbage collector generally throws objects out, that are no longer referenced.

In your case, this would be after the `print()` in the while loop completes, and starts over - replacing the previous data in `lp` with a new reference. The old object is hence no longer referenced and garbage collected.

Afaik, this holds True for multi-threaded programs, as well as single-threaded programs.

Aside from the python documentation, [this post](https://www.quora.com/How-does-garbage-collection-in-Python-work) has a well-written summary on when the garbage collector in python does its thing.